# Finding finite basis of an ideal!

Tags: polynomials, ideals

I have the following question...

Set $I:= \{f \in\mathbb{Q}[X,Y] \mid \bar{f}(0,0)=0={\bar{f}(2,3)}\}$

I have proven that $I$ is an ideal... but the second part to the question is ..

Find a finite basis for $I$. Justify your answer....

I'm not sure how to find the finite basis as this isnt like any other example I've done.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by basis?  The ideal is a infinite dimensional over $\mathbb Q$ so do you mean a generating set over $\mathbb Q[x, y]$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry i just stated the question.. but it is relating to a generating set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general strategy is you should start by writing down a few polynomials that you know are in the ideal.  With a graded ring like $\mathbb Q[x, y]$ the smaller the degree the better as these are more likely to be useful as generators.  At some point you feel like you have them all and you need to provide an argument to that effect.  Here is a hint to get you started in your particular case:

1. Check that $f_1 = y - \frac{3}{2}x \in I$.
2. Give an argument as to why, given any $h \in I$, we can write $h = h_1(x, y)f_1 + h_2(x)$ where, explicitly, $h_1$ is a polynomial in both $x$ and $y$ but $h_2$ is a polynomial in only the variable $x$.

Now you'll need one more generator, $f_2$, to get the entire ideal.  By the arguments above you know $f_2$ can be chosen as a polynomial in just the variable $x$.  So try and think of the smallest degree polynomial you can find in $I$ and then see if you can argue that those two polynomials, $f_1$ and $f_2$, generate all of $I$.